# How to refresh the div tag every 500 - 1000ms?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, refresh

I have this ***div*** which contents depends of the current time of HTML embedded media player.

```
<div id = "myId">
<s:iterator value="timeLine.getFrameByTime('22').slide.indices">
    <a href="javascript:setCurrentTime('<s:property value="timeLine.getFrameByTime('22').slide.firstOccurence"/>')">
             <s:property value="text"/>
       </a>
</s:iterator>
</div>
```

Number 22 is hardcoded. It should be return value of function below.

JavaScript code:

```
function getCurrentTime() {
    return document.getElementById('video').controls.currentPositionString;
}

function setCurrentTime(time) { 
    document.getElementById('video').controls.currentPosition = parseFloat(time);
}
```

That ***div*** above should be refreshed for every 500ms. I don't think that AJAX and JSON is the solution because server would be overloaded then.

Is there a way to refresh that ***div*** from JavaScript (jQuery) while loop which sleeps for 500 - 1000ms?

EDIT: By refresh I mean, content of that ***div*** should be changed. I know the current time of my media player and I know what is the content for particular time input. Now I need the mechanism to ask my media player for it's time and change the ***div*** content.

The question is: Use AJAX for every 500ms and call my method on server which gives me contents for particular time input or load the whole data on page initialize and implement logic in JavaScript which shows only the part of that data depending on current time?

Comment: refresh with server postback?

Comment: yes please define what you mean by refresh

Comment: I edited the question. I think it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery SetInterval Function for this purpose...

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

This can be used to either refresh the div with contents from client side cache or to send server requests to retrieve data to refresh the div.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a `<div>`?  If you can use an `<iframe>` instead, the solution is simpler and can use HTML features.  This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403864/how-to-reload-an-iframe-every-x-seconds) describes how to use a `<meta>` tag to refresh automatically every X seconds.

Comment: well, it doesn't matter if it is div or iframe, but but I have to refresh it with different data. Based on stackOverflow answer I don't see how it can be done. I just want to refresh that particular div/iframe, not the whole document.

Comment: and here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp it says that it should not be used. hmm. tnx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you output all content of your timeLine data to javascript, if possible.

```
var timeLineIndices = [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' ];
var getFrameSlideIndicesByTime = function(time){
    return timeLineIndices[time];
}
```

Effectively implementing timeLine.getFrameByTime('22').slide.indices at client side by javascript.

If outputing all frames data is too large, consider output only the frames according to your 500 - 1000ms interval.